minimal uncountable well-ordered set, the set of elements with no immediate predecessors is uncountable
I recently learned about the minimal uncountable well-ordered set, and although I know this question has been asked before, I solved it differently and was hoping someone could see if this was correct.
Let $X$ be the subset of $S_\Omega$ (the minimal uncountable well-ordered set) of elements with no immediate predecessors and I want to show it is uncountable. What I did is assume $X$ was countable, so $X^C$ is uncountable, and then for $x_i \in X^C$ indexed by some set $I$ define $x_i=x_{i1}$and $x_{i2}$ the immediate predecessors of $x_{i1}$ and so on, and there exists some $u_i$ in the chain $u_i = x_{iN} < ...<x_{i1}$, where $u_i \in X$ because otherwise we would have a set with no minimal element (obtained by starting from $x_{i1}$ and repeatedly appending immediate precursors). But the $u_i$ are countable (as elements of $X$) so by the pigeonhole principle we have some $u_j$ with multiple immediate successors, which is a contradiction.
Specifically, I want to check the argument that the set of elements with a predecessor being uncountable contradicts that the set of elements without a predecessor is countable.

I do not see the contradiction that you see. Could you explain (via editing your post) further? Specifically, I do not see how we have a $u_j$ with multiple immediate successors?

What is $S_\Omega$?

@LeeMosher I assume it is the set of all countable ordinals, or some order equivalent thing, (based on the post being about “the least uncountable ordinal”)

Perhaps, but I would like to hear the OP weigh in on this question.

Also, please read the text of the solution-verification tag, where you can find these words: "... the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so."

Please see edits; thank you for your input!

Everything looks fine up to the clause "so by the pigeonhole principle we have...". That's rather too vague, I don't know how you are applying the pigeonhole principle --- the pigeonhole principle is generally concerned with the behavior of some function from some set to another set of strictly smaller cardinality, but you have not specified those sets nor the function. So I don't know how you are coming up with the existence of some $u_j$ with multiple immediate successors.
Instead I would start, as you do, from countability of the set of $u_i$'s. The set of their immediate successors $s(u_i)$ is countable, and the set of their immediate successors $s^2(u_i)$ is countable, and so on, hence the set $\{s^k(u_i)\}_k$ is countable. But that set contains every $x_i$, so $X^C$ is countable, which is a contradiction.

Thanks so much this is very helpful. One thing that confused me here is that this argument applies to a general well-ordered uncountable set and does not make use of the special property of the minimal uncountable well-ordered set. Is this true, that in a well-ordered uncountable set must have uncountable elements without a direct predecessor?

Yes, that's true. And your proof, adjusted with the bit in my answer, does show that. You can also derive this generalization from the special case of $S_\Omega$ (the minimal uncountable ordinal), because $S_\Omega$ is (order isomorphic to) an initial segment of every uncountable ordinal.
